# Is Bacula presents snapshot feature in free edition?

Tags: snapshot, bacula

I have problem with Bacula.

Is there snapshot feature in Bacula free edition?

These days i'm searching for snapshot feature in Bacula free edition
but it seems like only presented in enterprise edition only.

thanks.

Comment: Bacula seems to be a networking tool. if it is this is off topic. maybe try : https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Snapshotify Plugin is available at Bacula Enterprise only. But some time ago Kern sent bacula status to the bacula-users list where he promise to include snapshot management in the community version:

> A few of these new features will be: 
>   (...)
>   3. New automatic snapshot management functions for the community version.

What I can see in the current code, there are some bits of code for this functionality already available.

Comment: Thanks! Can i read that status Kern sended? please share me that link. thank you.

Comment: Well, I have it on the email (as it was sent to bacula-users mailing list) but I googled for it 3 secs: http://bacula.10910.n7.nabble.com/Bacula-Status-Report-2-of-2-td80232.html